# Is there a way to create a project template for an unmanaged C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, project-template

I've been looking at the MS site [How to: Create Project Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8(v=vs.120).aspx) trying to figure out how to make a project template based on a sample project that I wish to deploy to my company.  However in this page: [How to: Create Item Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh(v=vs.120).aspx), it says:

> Note
>   You cannot export templates for C++ projects

So now I'm a bit confused and annoyed.  Can I make a C++ project template or not?  If not, then how does MS do it?  If so, how do I do it.

Comment: I feel a silly strong urge to mention that `export` of templates was never implemented in Visual C++ (as far as I know it was only ever implemented in Comeau C++ and halfway documented in the Intel compiler), and was removed in C++11. But that's something else. Just as Visual Studio export of an item template is something else than export of a project template.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, you should feel silly since this has nothing to do with C++ templates, and everything to do with VS project template mechanism.

Comment: Thank you all (two so far) for trying to clarify something you haven't read. Why not read it first. That's my view.

Comment: @Adrian, Have you actually tried? It is not a problem in VS2015 - maybe they patched it in VS2013 by now.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, tl;dr. Why even bring that up?  It isn't relevant to the question.  You even say so in "But that's something else". o.O

Comment: @MikeMB, I'm currently trying, but I'm finding the docs are sketchy.

Comment: Looks like this is to be done manually in 2013. :(  But I can't find any documentation to do this manually. :(